# Angular-filemanager usage. How to?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sails.js

I am trying to open the angular-filemanager in a web page.
I configured it as said in the documentation at https://github.com/joni2back/angular-filemanager

However, I got an error when editing the app.config as it is said.
The code is this:

```
var appName = angular.module('appName', ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'fileManagerConfigProvider',
function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, config) {...}
```

The error is the following:

> angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to
>   instantiate module playty due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown
>   provider: fileManagerConfigProvider

So I changed it to:

```
var appName = angular.module('appName', ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider',
function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    ...
}]).service(['fileManagerConfigProvider', function(config) {
    var defaults = config.$get();

    config.set({
    appName: 'angular-filemanager',
    pickCallback: function(item) {
        var msg = 'Picked %s "%s" for external use'
        .replace('%s', item.type)
        .replace('%s', item.fullPath());
        window.alert(msg);
    },

    allowedActions: angular.extend(defaults.allowedActions, {
        pickFiles: true,
        pickFolders: false,
        }),
    });
}]);
```

There are no errors now. Is this correct?
If it is, how do I open the angular-filemanager window now? I have read that I have to place   in the html. But what then?

Comment: Did you remember to include the script for the file manager in `ìndex.html`? Forgetting it could cause the first error

Comment: I have followed the steps 1,2 and 3 and added the "Extending the configuration file" part, @Fissio

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it gets fixed including ALL the components the example indicates:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-filemanager/dist/angular-filemanager.min.js"></script>
```

And also expose to your module the component:

```
var appName = angular.module('appName', ['ngRoute', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'FileManagerApp'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'fileManagerConfigProvider',
function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, config) {...}
```